# Unable to transfer file content via `read` command

Tags: linux, command-line, read

I am trying read the contents of file into an array for further processing later. I am using `read` command for filling the array values. The following is a portion of my code that is causing the error.

```
read -r -a changefileArr < changedfile.txt
```

The following is the error I am getting

`read: bad option: -a`

I am using [this](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/read-command) website  as reference. I am using MAC OS Monterey (default shell is zsh). I need to use arrays because I need to do index based iterations. I would need index later in my code. If there is any better way(even if it doesn't use `read` command) kindly do comment.

Edit 1:

- I am using Linux terminal for testing out these commands. I didn't give any shebang.
- If `read -a` cannot be run in zsh. Can I get some equivalent command for zsh

Comment: even when I am using bash shell, I am able to view only one element (the first element alone) from the array. I am not able to get the entire list of elements

Comment: echo ${changefileArr[@]}

Comment: `zsh` uses `-A` for that like ksh did since the early 80s. A shame bash (which didn't have array support before 2.0 in 1996) chose to be incompatible and picked `-a` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're using `zsh` so you shouldn't expect `bash` built-in commands such as `read` necessarily to work.

If you type `bash` you'll land in an interactive `bash` shell where you will be able to continue the tutorial. Be aware that [the tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/read-command)'s handling of array variables is incorrect. Such variables (actually, all variables) should be double-quoted when used but it fails to do this.

```
read -r -a changefileArr < changedfile.txt      # Read line of items into array

printf "element: %s\n" "${changefileArr[@]}"    # An example
echo "${changefileArr[@]}"                      # Unpredictable if first value starts with a dash
echo ${changefileArr[@]}                        # WRONG !
```

NB You can write and use `bash` shell scripts even if you're using `zsh` as your default interactive shell.

Comment: Even If I follow the above after switching to bash shell, I am not able to display more than first element. Is there anything I'm missing.
P.S : changedfile.txt has more 20 lines. only 1st line is getting printed

Comment: @G.MAHESH, `read` reads $IFS-delimited words from one line, that's what it does. If you want to read separate lines, you need separate invocations of `read` with the splitting disabled, or `bash`'s `readarray` or do splitting on `$(<file)`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Can you submit your comment as an answer